# Why my applicationis is not appear in "Google Play Market" of the tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

I just published my application on "Google Play" but I noticed that the application in question appears browsing "Google Play" from smartphones, but does not appear on "Google Play" of my tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1. How come this problem?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:versionCode="32" android:versionName="4.7" 
    package="it.app.my">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>


<application android:debuggable="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">


    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It appears to be not compatible with your tablet.

Comment: Google play does provides filter .. check [link for ref](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#manifest-filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your manifest file:

**to Run Your App in Mobile Device as well Teblet (So, below code ll work for you).**

```
<supports-screens        
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

[Declaring an App is Only for Tablets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

[extra information for screen size](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

---

instead of above you can also do below way:

**Example 1**

The manifest declares `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3">` and does not include a `<supports-screens>` element.

**Result:** Google Play will not show the app to a user of a small-screen device, but will show it to users of normal and large-screen devices, unless other filters apply.

**Example 2**

The manifest declares `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4">` and does not include a `<supports-screens>` element.

### **Result:** Google Play will show the app to users on all devices, unless other filters apply.

**Example 3**

The manifest declares `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4">` and does not include a `<supports-screens>` element.

**Result:** Google Play will show the app to all users, unless other filters apply.

Comment: my app will also work on my tablet, because I already tested. So I would like it to appear on all the "google play" for each device

Comment: I edited my question, by inserting in the code the compatibility with the various displays. is correct what I did, to get the maximum support on all devices?

Comment: before do any thing read ans and all articles which i have post in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add targetSdkVersion declaration like this

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```